# Why doesn't adding more unicorn workers increase throughput (heroku, rails, postgres, memcachier)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

This is about a heroku, rails, postgres, memcachier app.

rails (3.2.16)
unicorn (4.8.3)

We are running a cluster of 2X (shared) heroku dynos. Each dyno is running unicorn with 3 workers which is about the limit of memory that can be handled with a 2X dyno.

We experience occasional instance failures where requests gradually get slower on a single instance, leading to that instance failing and requiring a restart. The rest of the cluster is unaffected. Newrelic often reports that networked operations postgres, cache or remote APIs are taking a long time in the transactions which it reports.

I suspect this is due to a small network failure/slow down which backs up the instance, causes the cache to appear unavailable (short timeout) which exacerbates the problem

To overcome this I would like to increase the concurrency and leave the world of shared dynos

Upgrading to Pm dynos seems like a good idea

Switching PM dynos on, I'm unable to increase the throughput by increasing the worker count. Heroku metrics report that dyno load goes up proportionally but heroku metrics do not report any increase in throughput (RPS) as I increase the worker count.

Adding a second dyno does double the reported throughput

So with that background. My question is:

**How might I research why increasing the unicorn worker count does not increase the reported throughput?**

Of course if you have suggestions on the direct cause I'd welcome those insights also. :)

**unicorn.rb**

```
UNICORN_WORKER_COUNT = (ENV.fetch('UNICORN_WORKER_COUNT', 3).to_i || 3) # amount of unicorn workers to spin up

puts "UNICORN_WORKER_COUNT=#{UNICORN_WORKER_COUNT}"

worker_processes UNICORN_WORKER_COUNT
timeout 35         # restarts workers that hang for 35 seconds, 5 seconds longer than heroku timeout

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  puts "Unicorn before_fork nr=#{worker.nr}"

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  puts "Unicorn after_fork nr=#{worker.nr}"

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

backlog_setting = Integer(ENV['UNICORN_BACKLOG'] || 1024)

puts "Unicorn PORT=#{ENV['PORT']} UNICORN_BACKLOG=#{backlog_setting}"

listen ENV['PORT'], :backlog => backlog_setting
```

Comment: did you increase the database connections with the worker count?

Comment: @phoet - Interesting thought thanks, how/where would that be done?

Comment: @stujo, likely with the `pool` setting in your `database.yml`. Check out [this heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#connection-pool).

Comment: Thanks @phoet and @taylorthurlow! I don't this we have a pool, because each unicorn worker is a single processing thread. This area sounds promising though, it makes sense that there is some limit somewhere but I believe currently each worker has it's own connection

Comment: true, unicorn uses a process based concurrency model. heroku recommends using puma or similar servers that use lightweight threads to handle more concurrent requests. those require scaling the pool alongside the thread-count.

Comment: Heroku's throughput measurement is based on your actual load. Unless your load is changing (more requests being sent to your app), your throughput won't change.

"Adding a second dyno does double the reported throughput" <-- Very curious how this was the case if your load did not change.

What you _should_ notice with more workers is a decrease in request queue time (if that was an issue to begin with).

Comment: Thanks @AdamMcCrea I was using a load generated from my laptop. The throughput was reported by heroku metrics in requests per second. The number of requests processed by a single dyno increased as I added workers up to 3. Then was flat as I added more workers to a single dyno. Adding a second dyno doubled the reported throughput in requests per second. I will review the newrelic logs to see how the request queue time varied